# How to start modeling headlights of an Audi r8 v10 plus

Tags: modeling

Hey guys i´m currently working on an model of an r8 v10 plus, eventhough i´m
a beginner i managed to make it look quite good but for now i only have realy easy place holder lights. I tried a few times to model the proper head and braking lights but i just have no idea how to start. Would you use a texture for most of it? How would you make the material? I just have no idea, it would be great if you could give me an push in the right direction.

Here is an picture
[image]

Comment: What is an r8 v10 plus? Could you some images to your question showing what you got and what you are unhappy about?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the op forgot the most important bit in the title of that car the brand: Audi R8 V10 plus

Comment: thought everybody knows what an audi r8 v10 plus is, btw. it´s the 2016 version